# The server returned an error: 404 not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to get xml-data from an api like this:

```
try
{
    var url = "http://myapi.dev.io/xml/" + peNo;

    CookieContainer myContainer = new CookieContainer();
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("restuser", "rest2user");
    request.CookieContainer = myContainer;
    request.PreAuthenticate = true;

    using (var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var data = new AssetXmlDTO() { AssetXml = reader.ReadToEnd() };
            return data;
        }
    }
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
    {
        if (((HttpWebResponse)ex.Response).StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        {
            // handle the 404 here
            return null;
        }
}
```

But everytime I run the code, I get an 404...

However, If i copy the url and navigates to it via the browser, it works. I get the following xml-result when doing so:

```
<result>
service/assets/asset/id/9301246/version/7/element/actual/0/storage/preview/file/09078960.jpg
</result>
```

So why do I get an 404 in my code when actually does exists? Any idea?

Comment: Can you stick a breakpoint on the first line in the try, and post the value of `peNo` as well as the url that you're pasting into the browser.

Comment: @BarryO'Kane http://myapi.dev.io/xml/PE1234 is the result of the url-string. And when I paste it in, it works.

Comment: I can't access that url. Are you running it locally or anything/

Comment: @BarryO'Kane it's locally.

Comment: Chances are that it's either the url being built in the first line of code is incorrect, or you're passing the credentials wrongly. Should they be in cookies? I've typically seen this done with basic authentication.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should add some attributs to your HttpWebRequest like :

```
request.Method = "POST"; 
string _yourPostData = peNo;
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_yourPostData );
request.ContentType = "application/xml";
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;  
Stream _dataStream = request.GetRequestStream(); 
_dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
_dataStream.Close();
// Get the response.  
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```